# How can I write the bottom line in the equation?

Tags: equations

[image]

Hello everyone, I want to write this equation in LaTeX, but I can't get the equation starting with H1 to the bottom line. I would be very happy if you could help with this.

```
    {{\mathcal{H}}_{0}}:y\left[ n \right]=w\left[ n \right]\ n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N
\\  {{\mathcal{H}}_{1}}:y\left[ n \right]=x\left[ n \right]+w\left[ n \right]\ n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  the `split` environment. I took  the liberty to remove the unnecessary `\left \right` pairs, and simplified a bit your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \mathcal{H}_{0}:y[n] & =w[n],\quad n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N \\
 \mathcal{H}_{1}:y[ n] & =x[n]+w[n],\quad n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both very much.

Comment: @ZangLi Thank you for your green check mark ...but with a lot of sincerity it is of Bernard. Please, can you switch it to Bernard? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    {{\mathcal{H}}_{0}}&:y\left[ n \right]=w\left[ n \right]\ n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N\\
    {{\mathcal{H}}_{1}}&:y\left[ n \right]=x\left[ n \right]+w\left[ n \right]\ n=1,2,\ \ldots ,\ N
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

then you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility it is to use `array` enviroment. I have build this MWE looking your image and I have used the same fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \pazocal{H}_{0}\colon y[n]&=w[n],\quad n=1,2,\ldots, N \\
 \pazocal{H}_{1}\colon y[n]&=x[n]+w[n],\quad n=1,2,\ldots, N
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]